# Php echo is not working in my HTML woocommerce custom email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom email which is triggered if product has meta in woocommerce order. Everything works great but I can't get the billing_first_name into the text. I use `<?php echo $menomeno; ?>`which is declared as `$order->get_billing_first_name();` and I've also tried `<?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name(); ?>` Nothing worked, I get everytime empty string in the email. I have also tried to use `sprintf` method but it did not sent email. Any ideas how may I solve this?

Note: HTML code is shortened, its much bigger but I did not want to post the whole big code because its not neccesary in this situation when we need to get billing name in the part of the code.

```
function send_a_custom_email( $order_id, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();
    $product_ids = array( ); // Initializing
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $customer_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $meta_data  = $item->get_meta('meno'); // Zisti ake je meno
        $venovanie = $item->get_meta('venovanie'); // // Zisti ake je venovanie
        $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
        
        if( empty($meta_data) ) {
            $product_ids[] = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
        }
    }

 if ( empty($product_ids) && $product_id == 2805 ) {
        $recipient = $customer_email; // Set email recipient
        $menomeno = $customer_name;
        $subject   = sprintf( __('Order #%d: Has missing item meta data'), $order_id );
        $content   = '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="text_block" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word;" width="100%">
<tr>
<td style="padding-bottom:30px;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-top:15px;">
<div style="font-family: sans-serif">
<div style="font-size: 14px; mso-line-height-alt: 25.2px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 1.8; font-family: Montserrat, Trebuchet MS, Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, Tahoma, sans-serif;">
<p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; text-align: center;"><strong>S láskou <?php echo $menomeno; ?>
</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>';

//wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $content ); // Send email
        $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'DTerapia s láskou' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $content );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have `<?php` when you're already inside a PHP block and can't use `echo` inside a string. You should [concatenate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the value instead. `$content = 'foo ' . $menomeno . ' bar';`

Comment: so how could I get the billing_first_name into the HTML line where it is located

Comment: <p style="margin: 0; font-size: 16px; text-align: center;"><strong>S láskou <?php echo $menomeno; ?>
</strong></p>

How to modify this to get order billing first name?

Comment: Example concatenation should work.. `<strong>S láskou ' . $customer_name . '</strong>`

Comment: But when I will use ' as quote symbols it will close my content section for the html and I will get error.

Comment: @LuboMasura you close then open again... `'This is ' . $some . ' text'`

Comment: I literally told you how to write it in the first comment: `$content = 'some text' . $yourVariable . ' some more text';` Did you read the link in the first comment? You should also read the manual [about strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: @LuboMasura as M. Eriksson said. I missed his comment.

Comment: @Bossman it worked. You are right. Thank you! You could also post this comment as an answer so I could mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you were also right. Both of you thanks

Comment: @M.Eriksson He was first, if he chooses to post the answer he can have the like juice :)

Comment: @M.Eriksson I agree with Bossman so its your turn to post the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this explanation about concatenation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php